# How to smooth the convex shapes of a bump map?

Tags: node-editor, displacement, bump

I've created (using texture painting) a bump map pattern.
[image]
Pattern is all right, but it has sharp, distinct edges, however I need the shapes of this pattern to be extra smooth, soft (more like the shape on the second picture below).

[image]

Could you please share a way to smooth these shapes? If there is such a way:)

Comment: Your black and white image you use as pattern needs to be blurred, not sharp, you can blur it in an image app like Photoshop or Krita

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure the texture has smooth gradients in it.

If you just paint something with texture paint, the greyscale image will not have gradients that match the shape of bump you want. You would need to smooth the bump map texture somehow. It might be convenient to do it in some software dedicated to image editing, but you could also use Blender's Compositor. One way could be to make a black and white version of it in the compositor, blur it but also use it as a mask, so you retain sharp edges around:

[image]

That's Compositor. I painted the texture, saved it, loaded it into Compositor, then saved the output and loaded it back to the material of the object in my screenshot.

Keep in mind that bump maps are not really meant for big details. If you actually needed detail as big on render as in your example, you might run into problems that may only be possible to solve using some other techniques than bump maps. On the other hand, if it works - it works.

Comment: wow, many thanks! I'll try it fist thing today!

Comment: I now have a different problem – layers with pixels:) Can you please drop me a hint how to get rid of it? (it's 16 bit image)
https://monosnap.com/file/iweQd6TSiQXif4Llw6PR7UKETBDBWv

Comment: This is probably caused by the settings of your image texture, it needs to be PNG, 32-Bit Float, and the Image Texture node needs to be set to Non-Color instead of sRGB and Cubic instead of Linear

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no, I've checked these things already and it didn't help (although blender saves my image texture as a 16-bit image and I can't see how to fix that)

Comment: Yeah, well, bump map can only go so far - it's not perfect. 32 bit EXR format has way more precision, so you can improve situation with it, but there are limits. Like I mentioned in the answer - you might need to consider other techniques instead of bump maps if you need to visualise big shapes - bump maps are not intended for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the shape to be smooth you need to use a blurred black and white pattern. Note that the settings of your image texture needs to be PNG and *16-Bit Float* (or *32-Bit Float* ?), and the *Image Texture* node needs to be set to *Non-Color* instead of *sRGB* and *Cubic* instead of *Linear*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this part worked:) now I have to deal with pixels https://monosnap.com/file/iweQd6TSiQXif4Llw6PR7UKETBDBWv (I see you answered to that above)

Comment: Can you please pack your image and share your file? If you've converted to 16-Bit Float after it was 8-Bit it won't work, what you can try is convert to 16-Bit Float or 32-Bit Float, blur, save the image, import again in Blender @Marfa Razmakhova

Comment: Did you mean EXR?

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys PNG should also work fine

Comment: PNG format does not support 32 bits, does it?

Comment: @Martynas Žiemys You may be right, it's just that the 32-Bit option is available in Krita for a PNG file but it may be limited to 16-Bit?

Comment: Anyway I can't see any difference between an EXR and a PNG

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14MIfLW-uZwsCokAdJL9faIjJkb4JE01K/view?usp=share_link

I packed blender file, texture I drew using texture painting + modified texture (after compositing)

Comment: It doesn't seem too bad to me: https://zupimages.net/up/23/16/14te.jpg

Comment: that's what I see:) https://monosnap.com/file/sxVbhlE4XN5bJTl8o6kNmL8mg53kcg

Comment: Maybe something in my scene settings? I'm lost:)

Comment: The image you use for the Bump is not blurred, plus it's 8-Bit, it needs to be in 16-Bit, then blur it, and import again @Marfa Razmakhova